# git push -u origin master hangs up despite increasing postBuffer to 500MB

Tags: git, large-files, freeze, git-push

I'm pushing about 50mb. The terminal hangs after the Total line and after several hours it returns

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error - 36
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up to date
```

I have just got into coding and this is my first attempt at publishing a website using github. I use a mac.

So far the journey has been:

(In terminal, in the relevant directory)

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin (my-URL-here)
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First Commit"
$ git push -u origin master
```

at which point the terminal hung so I used...

```
$ git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
$ git push -u origin master
```

Here I am now stuck yet again!

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You have 50mb (code-) text files? IMHO, you should not track data with git. Just use a backup for that.

Comment: @Daniel Are you using any proxy server on your local machine to access your server?

Comment: @Christoph It's not just text files, no - I have 2 images and 1 video in the directory. I've been learning to code using codecademy, incl. how to publish websites so I wrote some HTML with a vid and some pictures and wanted to use github to publish it

Comment: @rango I use a wifi extender. Coredy N300. Could this be the root of the problem?

Comment: @DanielEggleton can't say much. refer to this post, if it might be helpful https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-push-fails-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-282988530.html

Comment: @rango as I had already tried increasing the postBuffer (helped, but not completely solved the problem), I tried the other 2 suggestions on this post.
1st: client_max_body_size 0 returned "command not found". Presumably because I do not use nginx. 
2nd (bypassing outbound proxy): Checking the configuration returned postBuffer = 524288000 and attempting to unset the system value returned "could not lock config file ... permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

Github normally gives a warning when pushing files larger than 50 MB. It doesn't allows files larger than 100MB to be pushed.

You can switch to git-lfs (Git Large File Storage) which is an extension of git that allows files large files to be worked with using git. Refer to https://help.github.com/articles/versioning-large-files/ and https://git-lfs.github.com/ for more details.

Comment: In order to pursue this solution I have installed XCode and in turn MacPorts, however to then install git-lfs I entered

    "port install git lfs" in terminal,

receiving error of insufficient privileges. Is the only solution to this to disable rootless?

Comment: @DanielEggleton Why don't you try installing using the source code. Refer to this article. https://help.github.com/articles/installing-git-large-file-storage/#platform-mac If problem persists, let me know.